# Get button text in Win32 form

Tags: c#, win32gui

I use the next code:

```
public static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        switch ((Commands)msg)
        {
            case Commands.WM_COMMAND:
                {

                    int wmEvent = Macro.HIWORD(wParam.ToInt32());
                    int id = Macro.LOWORD(wParam.ToInt32());
                    var dlg = Helpers.GetDlgItem(hWnd, id);

                    if (id == 3)
                    {
                        var result = MessageBox.Show("You wanna to save the file?", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                        if (result == DialogResult.No)
                            return new IntPtr(1);
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

        return CallWindowProc(original, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

if(id == 3) 3 is the id for button save.

I need change the if(id == 3) with (Button.text == "Save)

I try to use:
`SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, new IntPtr(length), builder); GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);`
But this functions don't give me any result.

Comment: You should use the correct tag. c# or Windows Form etc. Also, you might consider using UI Automation instead.

Comment: You already correctly ask for the button's handle (`var dlg = Helpers.GetDlgItem(hWnd, id);`), you should use this newly obtained handle (`dlg`) as an argument for your `GetWindowText` (instead of `hWnd`)